# What is the difference between "compose for rabbit" service and pure "rabbitMQ" service when using IBM cloud

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-cloud

I need to know basic difference between rabbitmq and "compose for rabbit" as a service in IBM cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one production-level RabbitMQ service in the [IBM Cloud catalog](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog): [Compose for RabbitMQ](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-rabbitmq).

The other service, [rabbitmq](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/rabbitmq), is an old, deprecated, experimental service that was part of Cloud Foundry. It should not be used and when you click it, it should redirect you to the Compose for RabbitMQ service.

Comment: So features like encryption, auto-scaling, and HA are the ones that are updated from deprecated RabbitMQ into new compose for RabbitMQ or are there any other updations to it?

Comment: There is no relation between the services.